# Why isn't the 16.04.1 Point Release available via update manager?

Tags: upgrade, updates

The point release is out but the update manager set to identify LTS releases gives no hint of 16.04.1.  Also setting update manager to "any release" only gives the option for 15.10.
Point release was released on 7/21/16.  Today is  7/27.  Is this timing normal?  Is 16.04.1 not a viable LTS?
Other threads indicate that a manual acquisition of 16.04.1 is possible.  If the point release bits are out there but update manager doesn't show it via the LTS option is 16.01.4 not a viable LTS?

Comment: While it isn't an option ATM, it will be later on.

Comment: Thx for the reply.  How can I get the same information you have?  The XX schedule indicates the point release was released last week.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule    It's just not clear how to figure out the releases if the release schedule is not updated.

Comment: I got that info from a moderator.

Comment: It'll be available at the same time as 14.04.5, no?

Comment: when will that be?

Comment: @ubuntulight Sometime in August, according to the wiki: [LTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2FSupport.A14.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support)

Comment: Just to close this loop.  I just checked my 14.04 LTS update manager and now the 16.04.1 LTS point release is now offered.  Today is exactly one week since the point release was unleashed.  So in my future calculus for point releases, one week could be considered normal timing.  Not scientific but it's not any worse than any other (lack) of information out there.  Thanks everyone.